# Unable to rename Files in a Next.js 13 project

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

So i have the following issue: Ever since Next.Js 13 updated the `pages` folder to a new `app` folder i cannot seem to be able to rename the regular default "Pages.tsx" file to something like "Home.tsx" or "Information.tsx" as everytime it breaks and sends me to a 404 Page, [Created by Next.Js] granted the first time i changed it it made it Home.tsx and it asked me to also change the next.js files (I cant remember which once hence the question) and I realized i made a error has Next.Js had a Captial letter glitch or something like that so i tried making it `home.tsx` but it didnt let me change the next.js files this time and still gave me  the same 404 error. Ever since then I have tried a days worth of googling and since its still kinda new I got next to no results.

I also tried creating a fresh Next.js project and trying to reproduce the auto navigation to the Next.js file and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the new app/ folder, your should create a folder with the route name and inside a page.tsx with the UI. [Define routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) -  [Pages and Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)

> app/page.tsx will be your 'default' page -> http://localhost:3000/

> app/information/page.tsx will be your ->
> http://localhost:3000/information

> app/about.tsx -> http://localhost:3000/about will be end in 404

[image]

Comment: And this could be done with custom ones as well? Instead of the presets Next.Js has given.

Comment: yes of course, actually there just a few presets.
For example you can do a app/one/two/three/custom/page.tsx with route 
http://localhost:3000/one/two/three/custom

Comment: Also you can do groups if you don't want to include the path on the route
app/(group)/one/page.tsx ->  localhost:3000/one
app/(group)/two/page.tsx ->  localhost:3000/two

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

Comment: And last one, also for dynamic routes
app/blog/[slug]/page.js ->  localhost:3000/blog/1
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes